# Interop Read Excelsheet Data from Horigental and vertical splitted pages

Tags: c#, interop

I need to import excel sheet data which is splitted in horizontally and vertically pages. I don't know how to read data from different number of splitted pages.

Is there any ways to get all pages list and then I will loop in page section to read data.

Thanks
Rakesh

Comment: You might want to check the EPPlus library. It can read excel as well: https://epplus.codeplex.com/documentation

Comment: Is it possible to read data from page breaks section

Comment: Not sure about that, but I did do a lot with it and found it much easier to handle than the excel interop.